# Angular 7: Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type

Tags: angular

I need to populate document object of the following type. I am using Angular 7 typescript. I am getting error Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'IDocumentDetails[]

```
export interface IDocumentUpload {
    fileDropEntry: NgxFileDropEntry;
    name: string;
    selectedDocumentItem: { 'Id': number; 'Name': string; }
    selectedDate: Date;

}

    export interface IDocumentDetails {
        name: string;
        file: any;
        documentTypeId: number;
        documentDate: Date;
    }


    export interface IDocuments {
        managerStrategyId: number;
        documentDetails: IDocumentDetails[];
    }

    documents: IDocuments;
    public files: IDocumentUpload[] = [];
```

I am getting error at this line of code

```
const documents: IDocumentDetails[] = this.files.map(doc =>
```

Code

```
const documents: IDocumentDetails[] = this.files.map(doc => {
                return  

                     [{ 
                        file: doc.fileDropEntry.fileEntry,
                        documentTypeId: doc.selectedDocumentItem.Id,
                        name: doc.name,
                        documentDate: doc.selectedDate
                    }];

            });

            this.documents = {managerStrategyId : 0, documentDetails: null};
            this.documents.managerStrategyId =  this.ManagerStrategyId;
            this.documents.documentDetails = documents;
```

Comment: Inside the map function, why do you return an array? I think you need to return an object.

Comment: I get error when i remove the square bracket

Comment: For e.g I get error Cannot find name 'documentTypeId'. Did you mean 'DocumentType'?

Comment: Try removing type on documents, and log documents: instead of ``const documents: IDocumentDetails[] = this.files.map(doc =>`` try ``const documents = this.files.map(doc =>``

Comment: Error still persist

Answer (score 3):

Since your return statement is not followed by a bracket '(', you are returning nothing.
try to place the curly bracket in the same line with the 'return' word.

Alos, like @JSON Derolu said, your .map function needs to return an object, not an array, so remove the square bracket.

try this code:

```
const documents: IDocumentDetails[] = this.files.map(doc => {
  return { // notice just a curly bracket, and in the same line with 'return'
    file: doc.fileDropEntry.fileEntry,
    documentTypeId: doc.selectedDocumentItem.Id,
    name: doc.name,
    documentDate: doc.selectedDate
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `const documents` is of type `IDocumentDetails[]` so you will need to return an object of type `IDocumentDetails` in your map function.

Try this.

```
const documents: IDocumentDetails[] = this.files.map((doc: IDocumentUpload): IDocumentDetails => {
  return {
    file: doc.fileDropEntry.fileEntry,
    documentTypeId: doc.selectedDocumentItem.Id,
    name: doc.name,
    documentDate: doc.selectedDate
  };
});
```

I have made your code more strongly typed by specifying the data types. Here the `doc` parameter in the map function is of type `IDocumentUpload` and the return type of the function is `IDocumentDetails` which the object you are returning in your map function.

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast your response like that:

```
const documents: IDocumentDetails[] = this.files.map(doc => {
            return 
                 [{ 
                    file: doc.fileDropEntry.fileEntry,
                    documentTypeId: doc.selectedDocumentItem.Id,
                    name: doc.name,
                    documentDate: doc.selectedDate
                }] as IDocumentDetails[];
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated the answer just try if its working?

```
const documents: IDocumentDetails[] = this.files.map((doc) => {
                return { 
                        file: doc.fileDropEntry.fileEntry,
                        documentTypeId: doc.selectedDocumentItem.Id,
                        name: doc.name,
                        documentDate: doc.selectedDate
                    };

            });

            this.documents = {managerStrategyId : 0, documentDetails: null};
            this.documents.managerStrategyId =  this.ManagerStrategyId;
            this.documents.documentDetails = documents;
```

Comment: I get error when i remove the square bracket. Fir e.g. Cannot find name 'documentTypeId'. Did you mean 'DocumentType'? Get the similar error for every line

Comment: do u have any stackblitz for this so we can also check whats the problem